# Setup Exchange OWA / Activesync on Android or iPhone

Tags: ios, outlook, exchange

I'm wondering whether there's a way I can configure my phone sync my corporate emails and calendars?

Sometimes when I'm away for meetings all day, I am not informed of any last minute meeting changes, or I could have forgotten about certain meetings during the day. It can get quite challenging and embarrassing managing such situations especially during days when I'm very mobile. I'm sure my boss isn't too happy about it.

The challenge is, my company has disabled the activesync feature on our corporate Exchange server.

The only solution I have now is to access OWA via my phone periodically to check my email. However, I can't possibly do that all the time. I found out also that there are phone apps that could do this, but I would need to pay for them. And in time to come, my company is going to disable OWA altogether, and that would render my small investment in the app worthless.

This makes me wonder whether is it really so complicated to configure one's phone to perform something so simple?

Since I could configure my personal laptop to download my corporate emails, there must be a workaround to still sync my phone to the Exchange server. However, there's no feature for me to configure certain settings on my phone which I could on my Outlook. For instance, "Exchange Proxy Settings" and "Only connect to proxy servers that have this principal name in their certificate". Does anyone know if there a way to force your phone to allow the same Outlook configurations?

Otherwise, is it possible to perform activesync natively via OWA instead?

If all else fails, I guess I could only either throw in the towel and find some other non-geeky ways to resolve this problem.